# Magento 2 error "Class does not exist" in checkout page after migrating from magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, migration

My newly installed Magento 2 was working perfectly until I migrated data from my old Magento 1.9.2.2 store using Magento 2 migration tool.

The problem now I am having is in checkout page, rest are ok.
When I go to checkout page, I have following error:

```
Class  does not exist
```

I have cleaned cache, view-processed, and static contents, nothing helped.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Class  does not exist
#0 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('')
#1 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('')
#2 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('')
#3 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('', Array)
#4 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create(NULL, Array)
#5 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php(537): Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create(NULL)
#6 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/AttributeMapper.php(65): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()
#7 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php(59): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper->map(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute))
#8 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php(67): Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor->process(Array)
#9 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml(21): Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage->getJsLayout()
#10 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/leihut...')
#11 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage), '/var/www/leihut...', Array)
#12 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/leihut...')
#13 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.root')
#16 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.root')
#17 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.root')
#18 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.root', true)
#19 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.root')
#20 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#21 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#22 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#23 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#24 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#25 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#26 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#27 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#28 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#29 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#30 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#31 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#32 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#33 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#34 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#35 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#36 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#37 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#38 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#39 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#40 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#41 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#42 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#43 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#44 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#45 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#46 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#47 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#48 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#49 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#50 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#51 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#53 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#54 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#55 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#56 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#57 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#58 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#59 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#60 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#61 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#62 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#63 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#64 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#65 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#66 /var/www/leihut.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#67 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 /var/www/leihut.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#69 /var/www/leihut.com/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#70 {main}
```